# Why can't Kami revive people himself?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

The eternal dragons are limited to the power of their makers, so wouldn't that mean that everything Shenron can do, Kami can do as well?

When Krillin tries to ask Shenron to defeat the Saiyans, the Dragon replies, that this is not in his power, as Kami, the one who created him, doesn't have that power either. But if Shenron can revive the dead, then why can't Kami do that as well?

I guess it would consider the dragons balls moot and they are an important part of the story, so it would be boring if Goku and his friends didn't have to look for them anymore.

Did Akira say anything about this?

Comment: I suppose it's just like the question, why didn't gandalf just use the eagles to fly the ring to mount doom and be done with it?  Takes away from the story and makes it awfully simple and boring.

Comment: @ggiaquin Gandalf's eagles could be explained by simply not being able to safely enter Mordor when Sauron was alive. For the sake of example, assume that Sauron's eye can shoot them out of the sky. Frodo took down the anti-eagle defense system (Sauron himself), thus allowing the eagles to safely enter and retrieve Frodo. This defense system would of course be part of the story in the interest of providing an interesting narrative, but there can still be an in-universe justification.

Comment: I actually searched a bit for this and I've seen that there is a thing called `Toriyama Inconsistency`, and people actually label this as one of them.

Comment: @flater how about the eagles at least bring them over the mountains I mean that could have helped a lot